# Twitter URL sharer: what does the 'Recommend @' field do?

Tags: twitter, sharing, tweet, twitter-integration

I would like to know what the 'Recommend @' field does on the Twitter URL sharer at https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet. The information appears in one of the HTML data tags, but then when I click on the Tweet button to preview the tweet nothing related to @JaneDoe shows up in the Tweet text (see image below).

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.com/" data-text="Yo,check out this site!!!" data-via="JohnDoe" data-size="large" data-related="JaneDoe" data-count="none" data-hashtags="AboutTheDoes">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

[image]

Here is the format of the URL which can be used by Twitter users to tweet about a web page (taken from the popup window shown above):

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=JohnDoeHashtag&original_referer=JohnDoeRefererURLEncoded&related=RelatedTwitterUserJaneDoe&text=MyTextHere&tw_p=tweetbutton&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&via=JohnDoe
```

Some of the fields are optional and are most likely used by Twitter for tracking purposes.

Comment: This is more of a question of using a single website that's not really a web application, per se.  Did you try the "contact us" link on the page?  It's probably something someone thought to throw on the form but never actually wired up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a specific web application.

Comment: My question is about Twitter so it should fit the [help center guidelines](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Using Twitter or a web-based Twitter reader, for example, would be on-topic, but this is more about how to generate a REST url using a widget for use in another site.

Comment: Are you saying programming for web app integration is off-topic? Well, I've posted other posts requesting information on how to best use specific features of popular web applications (please see my other posts), and they also got downvoted. At this point, it seems like just about everything relating to Web Apps is off-topic.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  Short of scripts written in Google spreadsheets, programming is off-topic on the site.  The site's scope is issues that end-users face when using a particular web application.

Comment: The help center should state: "Programming topics related to integrating software with existing web applications is off-topic." I hope someone will update the help center FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"JaneDoe" shows up in the `data-related` part of the tweet link. This information is used after the tweet button has been clicked to display the "suggested people to follow" prompt.

There is some more detail in the [tweet button developer documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button#related).

Comment: Thank you @JohnC for your answer. I also looked at the "Build Your Own Tweet Button" section of the page corresponding to the link you posted, and also found more information on the allowed query string parameters further up in the page. If I just use them as in the link I posted at the bottom of my post using the URL http://twitter.com/share and properly URLEncode everything after the ? mark in my HTML then I should be OK. Thanks!